# verbose_name_plural unexpected in a model?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've been doing some models of a future app, and, after adding verbose_name and verbose_name_plural to every entry on a working model, for making it 'beautiful', I've found that at validate time, Django doesn't like that, so it says:

```
  File "/home/andor/Documentos/desarrollo/grundymanage/../grundymanage/concursantes/models.py", line 4, in <module>
    class Concursante(models.Model):
  File "/home/andor/Documentos/desarrollo/grundymanage/../grundymanage/concursantes/models.py", line 7, in Concursante
    nombre_artistico = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre Artístico', verbose_name_plural='Nombres Artísticos', max_length=50)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'verbose_name_plural'
```

My model begins like this:

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

class Concursante(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre', max_length=30)
    apellidos = models.CharField(verbose_name='Apellidos', max_length=50)
    nombre_artistico = models.CharField(verbose_name='Nombre Artístico', verbose_name_plural='Nombres Artísticos', max_length=50)
```

Why 'he' didn't expects a plural verbose name there? Cannot live together with verbose_name?

FYI, this are my software versions:

- Ubuntu 8.04
- Python 2.5.2
- Django "1" "0" "final"
- Django ubuntu package version "1.0-1ubuntu1"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, `verbose_name_plural` is not an option on the field. It's a meta option for the model itself. A field has no plural name since, unless it's a many-to-many relationship (in which case Django will use the plural for the model pointed to by the relationship), there's only one entity in that field.

Here's the doc section: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#id3

Answer (score 5):

There is no `verbose_name_plural`.  It does not make sense to have both singular and plural for one field.  They are mutually exclusive.  In Django, they share the same name: `verbose_name`.

If your data represents multiple items (e.g. in a one-to-many relationship) use a plural form in `verbose_name`.  Otherwise, if your data represents a single item, use a singular form.

[Verbose name fields in the Django documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#verbose-field-names) provides some examples.